# Emacs- how should I customize the function behavior?

Tags: emacs

Please could you help me to customize function behavior in Emacs. The function is a part of the vhdl-mode.el.

```
(defun vhdl-template-begin-end (construct name margin &optional empty-lines)
  "Insert a begin ... end pair with optional name after the end.
Point is left between them."
  (let (position)
    (when (or empty-lines (eq vhdl-insert-empty-lines 'all)) (insert "\n"))
    (indent-to margin)
    (vhdl-insert-keyword "BEGIN")
    (when (and (or construct name) vhdl-self-insert-comments)
      (insert "  --")
      (when construct (insert " ") (vhdl-insert-keyword construct))
      (when name (insert " " name)))
    (insert "\n")
    (when (or empty-lines (eq vhdl-insert-empty-lines 'all)) (insert "\n"))
    (indent-to (+ margin vhdl-basic-offset))
    (setq position (point))
    (insert "\n")
    (when (or empty-lines (eq vhdl-insert-empty-lines 'all)) (insert "\n"))
    (indent-to margin)
    (vhdl-insert-keyword "END")
    (when construct (insert " ") (vhdl-insert-keyword construct))
    (insert (if name (concat " " name) "") ";")      ;; this is what I don't want here
    (goto-char position)))
```

I do not want from the function to print the construct name after the END keyword, the construct indicator (like process, entity, etc.) should remain. How should I customize this function and where should I put this customization? I met several possibilities (like defadvice or with-eval-after-load), but don't know which is suitable.

Comment: Maybe just remove this line (the second one, after inserting `END`)? 

`(when construct (insert " ") (vhdl-insert-keyword construct))`

Comment: This line is which I want to keep. I think about line after that, but this file is read-only, I can't edit it.

Comment: You could put a copy in your init file.  Wrap this around it: `(with-eval-after-load "vhdl-mode" ...)` where `...` is the modified function definition.